# Worst case scenario in binary search tree retrieval

Tags: graphs, search-trees, search-problem

Well, i have a binary search tree $T$ that is equilibrated by height witch has $2^d+c$ nodes ($c<2^d$). 
What is the number of comparisons that will occur in the worst case scenario, if we ask whether $k\in V(T)$ and why does it arise?

Comment: *Understandable justification* - don't expect us to solve your exercise for you. This won't help you understand the material.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: If the tree has height $h$ then the worst number of comparisons is ...? If the tree is "equilibrated by height" (I guess *balanced*) and has $n$ nodes then its height is ...?

Answer (score 0):

A balanced tree of height 0 has one node. A balanced tree of height 1 has three nodes. A balanced tree of height 2 has seven nodes. A balanced tree of height $h$ has $2^{h+1}-1$ nodes. Looks familiar?